# In SuiteCRM Dashbord is not showing in home page

Tags: suitecrm

I am new to SuiteCRM. I have installed it. It is working fine, but last day in home page dashboard is not showing. I am not getting any error. Earlier it was showing. Is there any enable option, to show the dashbord in how page. Perhaps I disabled that option.

In home page it is showing empty(blank).

Comment: Do you see buttons for adding new dashlets/dashboards?

Comment: @Star ,unfortunately I have enable ```Facebook```  in ```ACTIVITY STREAMS``` that is reason It was not showing.  Thanks